# mostrar imagen teniendo nombre en base de datos en android

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, imagen, programación-móvil

buenas, quisiera consultar, ya que no me funciono el metodo de guardar la imagen en la db, quisiera mostrar una imagen que tengo almacenada en el directorio de la misma aplicacion, pero necesitaria sacar el nombre de la base de datos, pero buscando no logro encontrar el metodo para realizarlo, actualmente estoy trabajandolo con java, sin frameworks

por lo que me solicitaron un poco mas de informacion,
actualmente, tengo almacenado en la db la imagen como un varbinary, al cual lo traigo por json como string y asi intentar hacer la conversion desde la app con este metodo

```
byte[] decodeString = new byte[0];
        try {
            decodeString = Base64.decode(i.getImagen(), Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap decodebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString,
               0, decodeString.length);
        imagen.setImageBitmap(decodebitmap);
```

pero el mismo me retorna error de conversion por base64,

ahora, consultando con un amigo, me dijo que lo que se puede hacer (teoricamente mas viable) es guardar la imagen dentro de un directorio en el filesystem hasheandola, y almacenar el nombre de la misma en la db para luego desencriptarla desde la app, y llamarla de forma externa, a lo que estuve buscando algo parecido pero no he logrado hacerme con algun dato para ello

Comment: no entendi nada , podrias incluir un poco lo que as intentando y que errores o donde te trancaste

Comment: Agrega el código como indica  Bruno. Debes aportar más información, ser más especifico, revisa [ask], saludos.